# Inverting "codimension matrix" for polytopes?

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, convex-polytopes, polytopes

Let $P$ be an abstract polytope. Let's construct its square matrix $A$ as follows. Its lines and columns are labelled by all faces of $P$, of all dimensions. Put $A(F_1,F_2)=t^m$ if $F_1$ is a subface of $F_2$ of codimension $m$, and $A(F_1,F_2)=0$ otherwise. So this will be an upper triangular matrix with 1's on the main diagonal. For example, below is the matrix for $P$ equal to an interval:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & t\\
0 & 1 & t \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Now a question: it seems that very often $A^{-1}$ can be obtained from $A$ by simply replacing $t^{n}$ by $t^{-n}$ for odd $n$. Is this always the case? Why?

Comment: Have you tried Moebius inversion? Face posets of polytopes (more generally, CW complexes) are Eulerian, i.e., their Moebius functions are very simple: $\pm 1$ depending on rank differences.

Comment: Oh. I don't even know the definition of Moebius functions for posets... Does this look like an ok source? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06664.pdf

Comment: That's probably a fine source; I guess the "canonical" source would be Chapter 3 of http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf.

Comment: Thanks you very much!